# Can't compile uclibc for newer kernels (missing syscalls)

Tags: uclibc

I'm having an issue building uclibc for rv32. It is missing a lot of syscalls.  I have a few of the errors listed below.

What are things to look for and approaches to take when trying to determine why uclibc is improperly trying to use syscalls.  I am on uclibc-1.0.45 and Linux 6.8-rc4.

Is there some general approach to take in situations like this?

```
  CC libc/sysdeps/linux/common/adjtimex.os
In file included from ./include/sys/syscall.h:33,
                 from libc/sysdeps/linux/common/adjtimex.c:9:
libc/sysdeps/linux/common/adjtimex.c: In function 'adjtimex':
./include/bits/syscalls-common.h:34:63: error: '__NR_adjtimex' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean '__adjtimex'?
```

```
  CC libc/sysdeps/linux/common/gettimeofday.os
In file included from ./include/sys/syscall.h:33,
                 from libc/sysdeps/linux/common/gettimeofday.c:9:
libc/sysdeps/linux/common/gettimeofday.c: In function 'gettimeofday':
./include/bits/syscalls-common.h:34:63: error: '__NR_gettimeofday' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'gettimeofday'?
   34 | # define INLINE_SYSCALL(name, nr, args...) INLINE_SYSCALL_NCS(__NR_##name, nr, args)
```